# Spring boot @ConfigurationProperties not loading from external properties file or class path property file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

Hi I am trying to use a reusable library that I have created using spring boot(2.0.5) from 2 applications I am able to bind properties from application.properties which is in my classpath to my bean as follows and I see the schemas being set through the setters in my debug in my first spring batch application which is also created with spring boot(2.0.5)

This is the property bean class in my library  which holds some service api- this library is just a jar package created with spring boot.

package com.test.lib.config

```
@ConfigurationProperties("job")

@PropertySources({

@PropertySource(value = "${ext.prop.dir}", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),

@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)

})

public class ServiceProperties {

           /**

           * Schema for the service

           */

           private String schema;


public String getSchema() {

                          return schema;

           }

           public void setSchema(String schema) {

                          this.schema = schema;
           }

}
```

And the config bean for this library is as follows in the same package.

```
@Configuration

@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServiceProperties.class)

@ComponentScan("com.test.lib")

 public class LibraryModuleConfig {
 }
```

This code works perfectly fine when called from a sprint boot spring batch application which includes this library as a dependency and the corresponding setters are called and I can see the schema set when I add `job.schema=testSchema` in application.properties

I try to use this same library in an existing spring mvc web application started from a tomcat server with external files directory as launch arguments( This application was not created with spring boot) and added the appropriate context:component-scan to include the beans (java config beans) from the library in the application-context(appn-context.xml). The job.schema property is passed from both application.properties file and even a external file in C drive as given by the ${ext.prop.dir}" in the @propertySources annotation. The schema property in ServiceProperties Bean never gets set and even the setters never get called in the debug. Why will this libray config bean not work in an existing spring mvc application but work with the spring batch application. Both of them add the library as a dependency. I have been at this at a long time and except for the spring property binding the other functionality seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

`@EnableConfigurationProperties` is a handy annotation that Spring Boot provides. (Spring MVC doesn't provides in default)

For a legacy Spring MVC app (specifically for Spring 3.x), you can use `@Value` annotation for the properties.

`@Value` annotation also works in Spring Boot so I guess you can make a change so that it works with older version (Spring 3.x) and newer version just works without changing anything at all.

Hope this helps! Happy Coding :)